# GROUP BY a specific order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a `GROUP BY` statement, with the grouped by column showing the item with the newest timestamp. However, I don't think it's possible to order BEFORE a `GROUP BY` statement. Is the following subselect the only way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

```
SELECT thread_id, content, timestamp FROM
(
  SELECT thread_id, content, timestamp FROM messaging_message 
  ORDER BY thread_id, timestamp desc
) combined 
GROUP BY thread_id
```

Note that for a given thread_id, there may be multiple messages associated to it, and thus multiple `content` and `timestamps` for each `thread_id`.

Comment: If you're grouping by `thread_id` what exacltly do you thik the values of `content` and `timestamp` whould be?

Comment: @WojtekT: `MAX(content, timestamp)` would be the content and timestamp of the most recent message in that message thread. Think gmail's inbox that shows the most recent message/timestamp for any message thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you want the most recent `content` per `thread_id`, use a `MAX()` aggregate to find the timestamp, and `JOIN` against it :

```
SELECT thread_id, content, timestamp 
FROM 
  messaging_message m
  JOIN (
     SELECT thread_id, MAX(timestamp) AS maxts
     FROM messaging_message 
     GROUP BY thread_id
  ) maxt ON m.thread_id = maxt.thread_id AND m.timestamp = maxt.maxts
```

The `ORDER BY` doesn't come into play at all by this method. It's all done by grouping.

MySQL, unlike other RDBMS doesn't strictly require you to have every `SELECT` column accounted for in the `GROUP BY`, so you could probably just do

```
SELECT thread_id, content, MAX(timestamp) AS maxts FROM messaging_message GROUP BY thread_id
```

However, that isn't portable and so I don't recommend it. Instead, the `JOIN` subquery returns the pair of `timestamp` and `thread_id`.  Those are used to match up against the related `content` and any other columns you may need from the row.  If you had a unique id on each row, you could also make a subquery which returns *only* the id for each `MAX(timestamp)` and use it inside an `IN()`.  But absent that unique id, a join against the `thread_id, timestamp` pair does the job.

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty new to SQL, could you please explain why you'd suggest using a `JOIN` here instead of a subselect?

Comment: @user1383058 Better explanation added.